# Matlab: how do I compare the values of two different matrices without using a for loop?

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices of equal dimensions.

How do I compare them, ie: numberOfFalsePositives = matA > 0 && matB < 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `&` instead of `&&`. The latter is only defined for scalar comparisons (see also the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html))

```
numberOfFalsePositives = matA>0 & matB<0;
```

If you want to know the number of false positives in addition to where they occur, you call

```
numberOfFalsePositives = nnz(numberOfFalsePositives);
```

as suggested by @woodchips.

Comment: Actually, that result only gives a boolean array. If the OP actually wants the number of true (non-zero) elements, then apply nnz to that result.